# Fixed with min function in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to use Fixed function. Below is how my data looks

```
Weeks   Customer_joined      Customer_activated
1             10                       4
2             20                      12
3             20                      15
4             40                      20
```

I am trying to find min activation rate in the group

So using`{FIXED [Weeks]:MIN([customer_activated]/[customer_joined])}`

Its giving me some weird result. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is this code ?

Comment: Ohh that's the code for the calculated field I am trying to create

Comment: In your real data set, do you ever have more than one data row with the same value for the Weeks field? If so, you usually want to aggregate your values before you divide.